# ¿Como modificar el color del icono de menu del Toolbar en Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawerlayout

Por defecto aparece blanco, lo que necesito es poner el fondo en Blanco y el icono en naranja, como podría cambiar el color del icono?

[image]

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Comment: que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Estoy probando con las propiedades del método Toolbar en la clase, pero aún no lo he logrado

Comment: No entiendo. Quieres cambiar el color de los iconos del Action Bar o del Status Bar?

Comment: Me refieron al ActionBar

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando un drawable y aplicandolé un filtro de color.

```
final Drawable menuIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu);
menuIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(menuIcon);
```